# Wordpress parameters for embedded ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress, though I'm a seasoned ASP/Delphi/SQL/Android developer. I am trying to work out how to do the following, but I cannot understand it even from all the postings and docs I've read. Does anyone know how to do this ?

I have a WordPress site, and I am embedding an ASPX page from another site as an embedded object. So far, so good. The user comes to the page by clicking a link in an email that has a parameter "InvoiceRef" in the query string.

I need to extract this ref, and pass it to the embedded HTML object, which is embedded like this :

object width="100%" height="663" data="http://domain/Invoice.aspx?InvoiceRef=**56556556**">

I need to get the query string that was passed to the WordPress page, and pass it to the embedded object in place of the 56556556 in the above code.

I'm sure this is simple to do, and someone has already had to do this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could use `$_GET["InvoiceRef"]` when you're outputting the `<object>` tag, but that may leave you open to injection attacks; you'd need to do some sanity-checking first.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I'd seen and tried that, but obviously I don't know if I'm doing it correctly. Where would it go in the object tag ?

Comment: It depends on how you're outputting the tag; are you using `echo`, returning it from a Wordpress function, or putting it into raw HTML?

Comment: Hi Adrian. I'm just putting raw HTML into the Source Code in the edit window.

Comment: Then something like `...InvoiceRef=<?= $_GET["InvoiceRef"] ?>">` is what you're after. BUT NOT EXACTLY THAT, as that introduces a serious security hole into your code. Put the value into a variable, and validate it (e.g. ensure it is numeric) first.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I'll use that as a start